# How can I add a ClassPreparedEvent to the EventQueue of my jdi vm

Tags: java, debugging, jdi

I am trying to code a debugger for a school project, so I can go through the code step by step and possibly skip over some methods, so far I have tried multiple approaches with the com.sun.jdi package but nothing has worked so far, as my jdi Event queue does not include a class-prepared event so I cannot set the breakpoints automatically. Is there a way around this, I have attached my code below.
Different approaches or solutions to the problem are welcome.

Thank you

This is my debugger class so far.

```java
package JPIDebugger;

import java.util.Map;

import com.sun.jdi.connect.Connector;
import com.sun.jdi.connect.LaunchingConnector;
import com.sun.jdi.event.*;
import com.sun.jdi.request.BreakpointRequest;
import com.sun.jdi.request.ClassPrepareRequest;
import com.sun.jdi.*;

public class JPIDebuggerClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[] breakPointLines = {6, 9};
        //VirtualMachine vm = null;
        try {
            // Starting the VM
            LaunchingConnector launchingConnector = Bootstrap.virtualMachineManager()
                    .defaultConnector();
            Map<String, Connector.Argument> arguments = launchingConnector.defaultArguments();
            arguments.get("main").setValue("JPIDebugger.Debuggee");
            VirtualMachine vm = launchingConnector.launch(arguments);

            // Setting up the class prepare request
            ClassPrepareRequest classPrepareRequest = vm.eventRequestManager().createClassPrepareRequest();
            classPrepareRequest.addClassFilter("JPIDebugger.Debuggee");
            classPrepareRequest.enable();
            // The classPrepareRequest should have put a ClassPreparedEvent in the event queue

            while (true) {
                EventQueue eventQueue = vm.eventQueue();
                EventSet eventSet = eventQueue.remove();
                EventIterator eventIterator = eventSet.eventIterator();
                System.out.println(eventIterator.toString() + " Event Set is received.");
                while (eventIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Event event = eventIterator.next();
                    System.out.println(event.toString() + " is the event");
                    if (event instanceof ClassPrepareEvent) {
                        System.out.println("Class is prepared");
                        ClassType classType = (ClassType) ((ClassPrepareEvent) event).referenceType();
                        for (int lineNumber : breakPointLines) {
                            Location location = classType.locationsOfLine(lineNumber).get(0);
                            BreakpointRequest bpReq = vm.eventRequestManager().createBreakpointRequest(location);
                            bpReq.enable();
                        }
                    }
                    if (event instanceof BreakpointEvent) {
                        System.out.println("Breakpoint is hit");
                        LocatableEvent locatableEvent = (LocatableEvent) event;
                        StackFrame stackFrame = locatableEvent.thread().frame(0);
                        if (stackFrame.location().toString().contains("JPIDebugger.Debuggee")) {
                            Map<LocalVariable, Value> visibleVariables = stackFrame
                                    .getValues(stackFrame.visibleVariables());
                            System.out.println("Variables at " + stackFrame.location().toString() + " > ");
                            for (Map.Entry<LocalVariable, Value> entry : visibleVariables.entrySet()) {
                                System.out.println(entry.getKey().name() + " = " + entry.getValue());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    vm.resume();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Debuggee class, that I am trying to "Debug" and set breakpoints in.

```java
package JPIDebugger;

public class Debuggee {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jpda = "Java Platform Debugger Architecture";
        System.out.println("Hi Everyone, Welcome to " + jpda); // add a break point here

        String jdi = "Java Debug Interface"; // add a break point here and also stepping in here
        String text = "Today, we'll dive into " + jdi;
        System.out.println(text);
    }

}
```

The Output I am getting is:

```
com.sun.tools.jdi.EventSetImpl$Itr@2957fcb0 Event Set is received.
VMStartEvent in thread main is the event
com.sun.tools.jdi.EventSetImpl$Itr@3b764bce Event Set is received.
VMDeathEvent is the event
com.sun.tools.jdi.EventSetImpl$Itr@45fe3ee3 Event Set is received.
VMDisconnectEvent is the event
com.sun.jdi.VMDisconnectedException
    at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi.EventQueueImpl.removeUnfiltered(EventQueueImpl.java:200)
    at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi.EventQueueImpl.remove(EventQueueImpl.java:97)
    at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi.EventQueueImpl.remove(EventQueueImpl.java:83)
    at JPIDebugger.JPIDebuggerClass.main(JPIDebuggerClass.java:31)
```

Comment: The debugger is a different JVM than the one you’re debugging. So there should be no expression like `Debuggee.class` in your debugger, as that implies that the class you’re debugging is contained in the codebase of your debugger. Further, don’t mix non-static methods like `setDebugClass` with static fields like `debugClass`. It’s not clear why you’re creating a `Tests` instance at all, when everything happens inside the static `main` method. So instead of `debugClass.getName()`, use the same class name you used a few lines earlier (`"Aaaaa.Debuggee"`) and check whether it’s the correct name…

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have updated the above code and apologize for the mess earlier. However, I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: You still have to realize that you have two different JVMs (still having the debugger and the code to debug in the same package doesn’t help this process). It’s just a guess, but you might have to set the class path of the newly launched JVM to find the main class. Since you’re not reading the sub process’s output and error streams, you won’t notice if it prints an error message about not finding the class (or any other error message).

Comment: Okay, how would I do that?

Comment: I suppose, the classpath is specified in the map argument like all other JVM parameters. The `VirtualMachine` has a [`process()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/jdk.jdi/com/sun/jdi/VirtualMachine.html#process()) method, so you can read [the stdout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()) and [the stderr](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream()) like with any other subprocess.

Comment: Classpath is passed via `arguments.get("options").setValue("-classpath actual-path");`